# ¿Como puedo validar si un archivo existe o no?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema al hacer una validacion para ver si un archivo existe o no, el problema es que en la validacion siempre me muestra que el archivo no existe, cuando cierro la aplicacon o cambio de activity y regreso a mi activity donde tengo la validacion me vuelve a creear el archivo en blanco

Esta es el codigo que implemento para hacer la validacion:

```
File fs = new File(FILE_NAME);

if(fs.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(this,"El archivo ya esta cargado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this,"El archivo no se ha generado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(notas.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

No se porque no entra a la primer validacion, el archivo estoy seguro de que se crea porque no me muestra error al guardar a algun registro, pero al entrar al if siempre muestra que el archivo no existe.

Esta es la clase completa donde tengo la validacion:

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaAdapter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private String archivo = "sesion.obj";
    private RecyclerView notasRecyclerView;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "notas.txt";
    private NotaAdapter adapter;
    private String notas="";
    private ServicioArchivo servicio = new ServicioArchivo(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        File fs = new File(FILE_NAME);

        if(fs.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"El archivo ya esta cargado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            try {
                Toast.makeText(this,"El archivo no se ha generado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(notas.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
/*
        notasRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_notas);
        try {
            adapter = new NotaAdapter(this, Arrays.asList(servicio.leerNotas()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(Principal.this, "No existe un archivo aún", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            adapter = new NotaAdapter(this, new ArrayList<String>());
            //servicio = new ServicioArchivo(this, servicio.cargar());
        }

        notasRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        notasRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        notasRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

*/

        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.ususesion);
            try {
                ObjectInputStream objInput = new ObjectInputStream(openFileInput(archivo));
                Usuario persona = (Usuario) objInput.readObject();
                objInput.close();
                text.setText(persona.toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sesión inicia con exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al cargar el archivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error clase no encontrada");
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        //este metodo es para obtener el id del menu de los
        //tres puntos
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.exportar){
            //onClickRadio(view);
        }else if(id == R.id.sesion){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.iniciotap){
            /*Parqueos parqueos = new Parqueos();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.exp, parqueos).commit();*/
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Parqueos");

        }else if(id == R.id.noticiastap){
            //Traemos al fragmento de noticias
            /*configuracion confi = new configuracion();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            //vamos a sustitur el contenedor del activity main por un nuevo fragment
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.exp, confi).commit();*/
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setSubtitle("Preferencias");


           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(android.R.id.content, new ConfiguracionesFragment())
                    .commit();

        }
        //Este codigo nos permite mostrar que menu esta seleccionado
        //para poder identificar que menu esta en uso
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    public void onClickAlerta(View view){

        Dialogo dialogo = new Dialogo();
        dialogo.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "confirmaciÃ³n");

    }

    public void actualizar(){
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.ususesion);
        final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        String value=(mSharedPreference.getString("opcion1", "Joder tio"));
        Toast.makeText(this,"Estas en el metodo de actualizar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        text.setText(value.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola añadiste los permisos `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> `
en el manifest ? estos te permiten acceso a leer archivos

Comment: @GustavoMora el archivo lo estoy generando de manera interna, hasta donde se no necesito esos permisos, ya que he echo algunas pruebas antes de la validacion que quiero implementar y no he usado esos permisos, ahora no se si para que busque el archivo es necesario dar esos permisos.

Comment: OK ok eso me pone en mejor contexto, Haz esto:
`File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename)` en lugar de esto: `File fs = new File(FILE_NAME);` me avisas. Te dejó la referencia de donde lo saqué [Documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: @GustavoMora Muchas gracias, yo tambien encontre la respuesta en otro post de aqui mismo, llegamos a la misma conclusion.

Comment: Perfecto tema cerrado entonces ?

Comment: Si, quiero ponerla como solucion a la pregunta.

Comment: @Kikehatake primero revisa los permisos, después cambia el path donde se escribira

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asegura primeramente que tienes definido el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

para dispositivos mayores a OS 6.0 debes pedirlos manualmente:

para android [Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) o posterior el permiso [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) (que implicitamente es tambien `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` se debe requerir manualmente, llama este método:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Puedes validar llamar el metodo unicamente el sistemas operativos mayores o igual a Android 6.0 :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

**Si tratas de crear un archivo de la forma que lo realizas, se tratará de crear en una ubicación del sistema que es de solo lectura, por lo tanto no se podrá realizar**:

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "notas.txt";
...
File fs = new File(FILE_NAME);
```

Cambia el path donde se escribira el archivo, por ejemplo en el almacenamiento interno:

```
File fs = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: Probe tu solucion y tambien me funciono, tengo otra duda si el archivo que se crea en el almacenamiento interno quiero moverlo al externo y borrarlo del interno, ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: para crearlo en el almacenamiento externo usa Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() en lugar de getFilesDir()  y para eliminarlo simplemente fs.delete();

Answer (score 0):

Haz esto: File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename) en lugar de esto: File fs = new File(FILE_NAME);

O

File fs = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME);